# Map controller property to different query parameter key

Tags: ember.js, query-string

In the EmberJS documentation there are two ways to map a controller property to a different query-param key.

#### Controller

In the [controller](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/routing/query-params/#toc_map-a-controller-s-property-to-a-different-query-param-key) by creating an object instead of a string in the `queryParams` array:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['page', 'filter', {
    category: 'articles_category'
  }],
  category: null,
  page: 1,
  filter: 'recent'
});
```

#### Route

In the [route](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_queryParams) by mapping with an `alias`:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    category: {
      // By default, the query param URL key is the same name as
      // the controller property name. Use `as` to specify a
      // different URL key.
      as: 'articles_category'
    }
  }
}
```

Which one is the best way to configure the mapping? And why are there two ways?